# What does "the squalor of toiling steel" mean?

Tags: sentence

This is a sentence from the book *Survival in Auschwitz.*

> Above us the malevolent clouds chase each other to separate us from the sun; **on all sides the squalor of the toiling steel closes in on us.**

I am confused about the second part, is it used as a metaphor for fatigue？

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading too much into it, but use of the definite article "the" in "the toiling steel" suggests that the author is referring to a specific aspect of the the environment that has already been described.  Without benefit of context, my guess would be that it refers to some kind of machinery.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's Lit Crit. @PellMel - checking the actual source, it seems the referent comes *after* the cited text (it's *the evil presence of the **barbed wire** that separates us from the world*).

Comment: 'Toiling' is obviously being used as a metaphor / personification (or perhaps in a slightly different way, as a transferred epithet). But this is deep stuff (ie unclear). Poetry, really.

Answer (score 3):

Primo Levi wrote in Italian.  You're reading a translation.  Here's the original:

> da ogni parte ci stringe lo squallore del ferro in travaglio.

In English, the word *squalor* means filth, especially that associated with poverty.  The translator has kept the cognate, but a better word for the Italian might be *misery*.  Levi is describing the work he and his fellow prisoners must do to unload trains coming into the camp, and he remarks in the next sentence about the evil presence of the barbed wire fences (*la presenza cattiva del filo spinato*).  So in context, another translation is

> from all sides the misery of the iron [i.e,. from the barbed wire] tightens around us in our labor

I believe that *travaglio* also has the same echo as the English *travail*, a painful labor.

Since I don't speak Italian, you might want to check my translation with our [Italian sister site](https://italian.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Great catch. +1